# Setting up conda environment with really old python version

Tags: python-2.7, conda

I am writing some python scripts for a computer that, for various reasons, is stuck at python v2.7.5 (upgrading is not an option).

I would like to set up a conda environment on my desktop to test the scripts out before transferring them to the production machine.

```sh
$ conda create --name py275 python=2.7.5
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=2.7.5

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

When I do `conda search python`, the oldest version available to me is 2.7.13, but if I go to anaconda.org and do a search, the [files for python 2.7.5](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python/files?version=2.7.5) are there and they appear to be in the main channel.

How can I point conda to those files to allow me to create the proper environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching long and hard for the answer, I found it after posting here. Python is in the `anaconda` channel, not the `main` channel.

```sh
$ conda create --name py275 -c anaconda python=2.7.5
```

Comment: Anaconda has switched the default channels since then, that's why the old versions are no longer found without specifying a channel.

Comment: I believe that the anaconda channel does not have version below 2.7.12. In order to create a new environment with this version I had to use the free channel:
    $ conda create --name py275 -c free python=2.7.5

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html